How do I rectify PWM and do I need to in this scenario?
Short question: Can I rectify PWM into a ≈constant DC voltage. If so, how (RC?). If RC, how do I find the values for R and C, if I need to be able to change the output voltage?
Long question (context) (maybe there are other solutions?): Im trying to control two brushless DC motors (fans) in a way that allows me to remotely reduce their power, therefore input voltage independently of each other. To do so remotely I will need an arduino board which can't handle 12V (maybe some can?), which means I'll also need a mosfet. Cooling the mosfet isn't a concern as I can just put it in the way of this ridiculous 100k rpm fan. The issue is reducing the gate voltage to control the output voltage. As far as I'm aware, no arduino board can reduce its output voltage without you physically turning its potentiometer (unless I'm wrong?). So that's what led me to the conclusion that I'll need to rectify PWM.
Any help would be much appreciated

what connections do you have available to the BLDC motor drivers?

Why can't you use the PWM directly on the fans like everybody else does?

The fan is part of the motor. Looks like one of those found in hair dryers, but not exactly the same

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by connections to the BLDC motor drivers, I can send the product link to amazon. For the motor itself - just + and -. https://www.amazon.com/Meokro-Brushless-100000RPM-High-Speed-Regulation/dp/B0CT3DH2P7/ref=asc_df_B0CT3DH2P7/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=703628499311&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=16656701777421492159&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=m&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=1026177&hvtargid=pla-2326748792785&psc=1&mcid=863dc9cf394f3656a94368314b1877e8&gad_source=1

Best to use a COTS motor driver. Building your own likely goes through lands of magic smoke.

This is not the best way to control the speed of a fan. Many have a PWM input or can take pwm directly.
